# Why ExecutorService.shutdownNow method can't stop the thread

Tags: java

```
package util.concurrent;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ShutdownDemo {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  executor.execute(new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run() {
    while(true){
     System.out.println("-- test --");
    }
   }

  });

  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);

  executor.shutdownNow();
 }
}
```

I have already invoked the shutdownNow method, why console continue to print "-- test --" ??

Answer (score 10):

Check out Thread.stop() in JavaDoc for the full reason:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()

Essentially, your thread must stop on it's own in order for your program to stay safe.  Just stopping a thread can leave programs in an unpredictable state where locks owned by the thread aren't freed and resources aren't given back to the OS.  Eventually leaving your program open to dead locks, memory leaks that can't be freed, and potentially affecting the stability of the OS as well too.  This really isn't any different if you were in C or any other language because stopping native threads has these problems.  Remember threads aren't processes they share memory and state with other threads so they must behave and cooperate.

Java works on interrupting threads as opposed to killing threads so threads must conform to this model when you write them.  Therefore, while(true) in your program is bad practice.  Instead you need to see if your thread has been interrupted, and shutdown on it's own.  Either with Thread.sleep and handling the InterruptedException properly.  Or checking Thread.isInterrupted() in your while loop.

Comment: But this is an instance of `Runnable` - where can we get at `Thread.isInterrupted()`? Also, if `shutdownNow()` attempts to interrupt our thread while it's not sleeping it will only set the interrupted flag and won't generate the `InterruptedException` when we `sleep()` again (if I understand the docs properly).

Comment: You can always get the thread executing any section of that code by using Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted().  Remember once a thread is interrupted any sleep() or wait() will generate an InterruptedException.

Comment: Cool, thanks (: Just to be sure I've understood properly, if our threads `interrupt()` is called and we're not sleep()ing, then later we `sleep()` for a bit, an `InterruptedException` is immediately generated? Presumably this is part of the Java spec and should be implemented in all VM's/standard libraries?

Comment: That's correct on both questions.  Remember, if you check isInterrupted() it clears the interrupt state for that Thread.  Same goes if the exception is thrown.  Once you check the interrupted state of the thread either with Thread.interrupted(), or by catching the InterruptedException it's not in the interrupted state anymore.  Java tells you once and only once.  What you do in response to it is your prerogative.

Comment: My doubt is that if shutDownNow() will stop threads when their tasks are executed, then what is the difference in shutDownNow() and shutdown()?  Can you tell me the case when shutDownNow() will stop a thread while executing the task?

Comment: The difference is quite simple.  shutdownNow() sends a interrupt() to each thread running a task.  If the task obeys the rules I stated above then task will stop as soon as possible, the task will not fully complete, and the ExecutorService will stop once all threads return to the pool.  shutdown() doesn't issue an interrupt() so it won't stop until all outstanding tasks fully complete.  shutdownNow() will not "stop" a thread as I've said above.  It only requests a thread to stop running code.  It's up to your code to obey that signal.

Answer (score 1):

From the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29), the ExecutorService#shutdownNow method is not guaranteed to actually stop the executing jobs.  You're much better off mutating some state variable that the long-running jobs will periodically check and on detecting the change, quit their run loop.

Comment: This is overstated.  Your state variable is no different than the state variable already provided by Thread.interrupted.  It will behave the exact same way.  While you can write code that will ensure a shutdownNow() won't complete - which is the author's fault - if you follow the rules I stated it will shutdown eventually.  Network calls eventually timeout, but while that time out hasn't expired the thread will have to wait until the timeout exception is thrown.  This is true for a shared state variable as well.